# NoReverseMatch with django

Tags: python, html, django, url, design-patterns

Hey I did build a website two weeks ago and it worked perfectly fine but when I am trying to open it without any changes the NoReverseMatch found error pops up. I do not understand why. Μy view for the auswertung method is defined as auswertung(request, pk)

This is my url code:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.main_page, name='main_page'),
url(r'^machine/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.auswertung, name='auswertung'),
url(r'^add$', views.add_machine, name='add_machine'),
url(r'^delete$', views.delete_machine, name='delete_machine'),
url(r'^machine/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.edit_machine, name='edit_machine')]
```

and this is the template which is producing the error:

```
    {% block content %}
    <div>
        <form class="MainFormClass" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ol class="orderdList">
            {% for machine in machines_only %}
                <p class="list-item">{{ machine.status.machine_number }}
                    <a href="{% url 'auswertung' pk=machine.status.machine_number %}">
                        {{ machine.status.machine_description }}
                    </a>
                    <img class="main-imageClass" src="{{machine.overallsrc}}"/>
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Please post the exception traceback.

Comment: Remove the `{% url %}` tag temporarily, and check that there are not any machines where `{{ machine.status.machine_number }}` is not set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed it and without it it just works fine.